# How to get one to many relations to a pivot

Tags: laravel, many-to-many, pivot-table, one-to-many, eloquent-relationship

I have 2 models Scheme & Sponsor with a many-to-many relationship with pivot SchemeSponsor.
The pivot table has a one-to-many relationship with ContributionRate. I want to get all sponsors related to a scheme together with all contributionrates.

Scheme

- id
- name

Sponsor

- id
- name

SchemeSponsor

- id
- sponsor_id
- scheme_id
- pivot_data

ContributionRate

- id
- scheme_sponsor_id
- rate

In the Sponsor model, I have this relationship

```
    public function contribution_rates()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        ContributionRates::class,
        SchemeSponsor::class,
        'sponsor_id',
        'scheme_sponsor_id',
        'id',
        'id'
    );
}
```

This relationship returns all contributionrates even where the Scheme - Sponsor relationship does not exist. I want the rates that are related to the Pivot table SchemeSponsor. How can I achieve this via eager loading?

Comment: Can you add your code? HasManyTrough should do the trick .

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are wanting to do a has-many-through-many-to-many which isn't supported by Laravel

You can, however, use [eloquent-has-many-deep](https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep) from [jonas-staudenm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4848587/jonas-staudenm) (which makes your life much easier)

e.i. on Your **Scheme Model**

```
use \Staudenmeir\EloquentHasManyDeep\HasRelationships;

public function sponsors() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Sponsor::class);
}

public function contributionRate() {
    return $this->hasManyDeep(
        ContributionRate::class,
        ['scheme_sponsor', Sponsor::class], // Pivot tables/models starting from the Parent
        [null, null, 'scheme_sponsor_id']
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used [EagerLoadPivotTrait](https://github.com/ajcastro/eager-load-pivot-relations) by [Arjon Jason Castro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5191738/arjon-jason-castro) to eager load pivot relations.

Scheme Model

```
class Scheme extends Model
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Sponsor::class)
        ->using(SchemeSponsor::class)
        ->withPivot(
            'pivot_data',
        );
}
```

Sponsor Model

```
use AjCastro\EagerLoadPivotRelations\EagerLoadPivotTrait;

class Sponsor extends Model
{
    use EagerLoadPivotTrait;

    return $this->belongsToMany(Scheme::class, 'scheme_sponsor')
        ->withPivot(
            'pivot_data',
        );
     }
```

Then, to get the Scheme together with Sponsors and Sponsors' contribution rates;

```
($scheme
        ->with('sponsors.pivot.contribution_rates')
        ->where('id', $scheme->id)->get()->toArray())[0]
```

I have noted in as much as $scheme is a single model, eagerloading sponsors with contribution rates returns all schemes with the sponsors plus the contribution rates.